# Find difference between two Future[Int] in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I am new to Scala and Futures. I a scenario like following -

```
val futureTotalCount : Future[Int]
val futureProcessedCount : Future[Int]

//I need to find the difference of above two futures to get unProcessedCount, something like-
val futureUnProcessedCount : Future[Int] = (futureTotalCount - futureProcessedCount)
```

Is something like this possible in Scala?

Comment: You may want to do some basic tutorial / course about futures and **Scala** in general.

Comment: I am doing that but I had an urgent submission so I needed something quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```scala
val futureTotalCount: Future[Int] = Future(2)
val futureProcessedCount: Future[Int] = Future(1)
    
val futureResultCount: Future[Int] = for{
  totalCount <- futureTotalCount
  processedCount <- futureProcessedCount 
} yield (totalCount - processedCount)

// Or:
val futureResultCount = futureTotalCount.flatMap { totalCount =>
  futureProcessedCount.map { processedCount =>
    totalCount - processedCount
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
futureTotalCount zip futureProcessedCount map { case(a,b) => a -  b }
```